# How to speedup Google Sheets script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have a script adapted to my needs which was created following [this](https://thedatalabs.org/automated-data-entry-form-google-sheet/).

I think my script is getting slower over time after adding more entry point in my sheet form.

```
// Function to submit the data to Database sheet
function submitDataX() {
     
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 

  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("AUser Form"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet

  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("database palsu"); ////delcare a variable and set with the Database worksheet

  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  // Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also
  // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Udah yakin input data?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Checking the user response and proceed with clearing the form if user selects Yes
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) 
  {return;//exit from this function
  } 
 
  //Validating the entry. If validation is true then proceed with transferring the data to Database sheet
 if (validateEntry()==true) {

    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Nama Jabatan
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H7").getValue()); //Tipe Jabatan
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C9").getValue()); //Kode Jabatan
    
    //entry kategori unit kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C13").getValue()); //unit kerjo-jpt madya
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C15").getValue()); // unit kerjo-jpt pratama
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C17").getValue()); //unit kerjo-administrator
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C19").getValue());// unit kerjo-pengawas
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C21").getValue());// Unit kerjo-pelaksana
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C23").getValue());// unit kerjo-jbt fungsional
    
    //entry kategori ikhtisar jabatan
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C25").getValue());// ikhtisar jabatan
    
    //entry kategori kualifikasi jabatan
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C29").getValue());// pendidikan formaal
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C31").getValue());// pendidikan dan pelatihan
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C33").getValue());// pengalaman kerja

    //////////BAGIAN URAIAN TUGAS

    //Uraian TUGAS 1
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B46").getValue()); // isian uraian tugas
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,13).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C46").getValue()); // isian hasil kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,14).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D46").getValue()); // isian jumlah hasil
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,15).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E46").getValue()); // isian waktu penyelesaian
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,16).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F46").getValue()); // isian waktu efektif
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,17).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G46").getValue()); // isian kebutuhan pegawai
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,18).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C48").getValue()); // isian hasil kerja luar
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,19).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B51").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,20).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C51").getValue()); // isian bahan kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,21).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B54").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,22).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C54").getValue()); // isian perangkat kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,23).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C56").getValue()); // isian tanggung jawab
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,24).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C58").getValue()); // isian wewenang
    
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,25).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B61").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,26).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C61").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,27).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D61").getValue()); //isian korelasi jabatan

    //Uraian TUGAS 2
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,26).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B68").getValue()); // isian uraian tugas
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,27).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C68").getValue()); // isian hasil kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,28).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D68").getValue()); // isian jumlah hasil
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,29).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E68").getValue()); // isian waktu penyelesaian
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,30).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F68").getValue()); // isian waktu efektif
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,31).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G68").getValue()); // isian kebutuhan pegawai
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,32).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C70").getValue()); // isian hasil kerja luar
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,33).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B73").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,34).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C73").getValue()); // isian bahan kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,35).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B76").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,36).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C76").getValue()); // isian perangkat kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,37).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C78").getValue()); // isian tanggung jawab
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,38).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C80").getValue()); // isian wewenang
    
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,40).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B83").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,41).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C83").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,27).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D83").getValue()); //isian korelasi jabatan

//Uraian TUGAS 3
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,26).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B68").getValue()); // isian uraian tugas
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,27).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C68").getValue()); // isian hasil kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,28).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D68").getValue()); // isian jumlah hasil
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,29).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E68").getValue()); // isian waktu penyelesaian
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,30).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F68").getValue()); // isian waktu efektif
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,31).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G68").getValue()); // isian kebutuhan pegawai
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,32).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C70").getValue()); // isian hasil kerja luar
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,33).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B73").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,34).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C73").getValue()); // isian bahan kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,35).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B76").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,36).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C76").getValue()); // isian perangkat kerja
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,37).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C78").getValue()); // isian tanggung jawab
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,38).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C80").getValue()); // isian wewenang
    
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,40).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B83").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,41).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C83").getValue()); datasheet.getRange(blankRow,27).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D83").getValue()); //isian korelasi jabatan

    // date function to update the current date and time as submittted on
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 25).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm'); //Submitted On
    
    //get the email address of the person running the script and update as Submitted By
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 26).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Submitted By
    
    ui.alert(' "Data Baru Tersimpan - Jabatan :' + shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue() +' "');
  
  //Clearnign the data from the Data Entry Form

    //shUserForm.getRange("C7").clear();
    //shUserForm.getRange("C9").clear();
    //shUserForm.getRange("C11").clear();
    //shUserForm.getRange("C13").clear();
    //shUserForm.getRange("C15").clear();
    //shUserForm.getRange("C17").clear();
    //shUserForm.getRange("C18").clear();

  //clear data rombongan ABK
  //shUserForm.getRange("C24").clear();
  //shUserForm.getRange("C25").clear();
      
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the size of the spreadsheet might have a performance effect on your script it is minimal compared to the execution time required by all the calls to the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet service (`getRange`, `getValue`, `setValue`), actually the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) suggest [use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). More specifically, instead of reading/writing one value at a time, read/write several of them at once. One way to reduce the read operations is by using `getDataRange` and `getValues` to read all the sheet values at once, and in this case as your script is writing the values on a new row at the end of the data range, you might use `appendRow`.

---

A not so "complicate" way to improve the performance of your script is to add

```
var values = shUserForm.getDataRange().getValues();
```

after

```
var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("AUser Form"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
```

then replace `shUserForm.getRange(a1Notation).getValue()` by `values[row][column]`

were `row` is the number of your the corresponding reference and `column` is the column number, i.e. the column number for A is 1, for B is 2 and so on.

Additionally to the above you could improve even further your script by replacing all code lines like `datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue());` by

```
var rowContent = [values[][],  /* add here as many as needed values[][] separated by commas*/ ];
datasheet.appendRow(rowContent);
```

Don't forget to put the corresponding row and column values inside `[][]`

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?getValues
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?getDataRange
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?appendRow#appendrowrowcontents

Comment: thank you so much, it worked