# Improve script performance

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I wanted to ask, if I can do anymore improvements regarding my runtime, currently it takes roughly 100s to finish my script(since adding the formatting script below). Before adding additional formatting, it took roughly 4-5 seconds to run all my code.

The script checks every cell in a given range, if it has a data validation linked to it and based on that to format the cell.

```
for(let i = 9; i < 32;i++){
for(let j = 2; j < 13; j++){
  cell = sheet.getRange(i,j)
  cellDataValCheck = sheet.getRange(i,j).getDataValidation()
  if(cellDataValCheck != null){
    cell
    .setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
    .setBackground("#FFFFFF")
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
  }else{
    cell.setBackground("#666666")
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I just posted and answer. If you need further help, please add more details and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices. In summary, whenever is possible you should avoid to use Google Apps Script methods in loops as they are slow. In example, instead of making the changes one cell at a time build an Array of Arrays of the background colors, then apply all the changes at once (instead of `setBackground` use `setBackgrounds`)

An option to improve the script results is to use [Advances Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets?hl=en), more specifically batchUpdate.

Related

- [How to speedup Google Sheets script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/159018/88163)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it a lot! I implemented your suggestion with the `setBackgrounds` , but there are still the borders left, for which there isn't any `setBorders` function. Do you might have an idea for that problem? I couldn't really find any solution.

Comment: I got a solution to my problem, if anyone is facing the same issue, this is how I solved it.  
This is how my sheet looks like: [screenshot of my sheet](https://imgur.com/a/zjoQbnL)  Instead of using `setBorder` for each cell, I was getting the range for each data validation "package", e.g. B9:B10, B12:B15 etc. . That ended up in 33 ranges, which I could format each with one single use of `setBorder` instead of 253 for each cell. Now my script takes 10secs instead of 100secs.
** Sorry for the very bad formatting, but the linkbreaks aren't working for me (Yes I did check the formatting page**